# node.js - How to return an ObjectId by name in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this code for setting an ObjectID to brand property of an productSchema:

```
productSchema.path('brand').set(function (namebrand) {
    var brandID;

    Brand.findOne({ 'name': namebrand }, 'id name', function (err, result){
        if (err) console.log(err);

        if (result){
            // console.log("Result: "+result);
            brandID =  result.id;

        } else {
            var newBrand = new Brand({name:namebrand});
            newBrand.save(function (err, newBrandID){
                console.log("newBrandID : "+newBrandID)
                brandID = newBrandID.id;
            });
        }
    });
    return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(brandID);
});
```

My problem is when the Brand ObjectID setter executes, I got differents ObjectId's 
for example:

```
return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(brandID); // 52ffaa218050b7c4652502de
console.log("newBrandID : "+newBrandID) // newBrandID : { __v: 0, name: 'new Brand name', _id: 52ffaa218050b7c4652502df }
```

So what is the correct way to do what I want? I'm a newbie on this :/

P.S.: Thanks in advance, and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a return value here. A mongoose `set` needs to be synchronous and you are making a DB query which is asynchronous. Look up the brand in the DB first, then set it on the product.

```
var productModel; // you must already have loaded this
var namebrand = "somebrand";
Brand.findOne({ 'name': namebrand }, 'id name', function (err, result){
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return;
    }
    if (result){
        productModel.brand = result._id;
    } else {
        var newBrand = new Brand({name:namebrand});
        productModel.brand = newBrand._id
        newBrand.save(function (err, newBrandID){
            console.log("newBrandID : "+newBrandID)
            brandID = newBrandID.id;
        });
    }
    productModel.save();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so I've to add that code in the Handler that saves a product, right?

Comment: Yes, correct. In general my advice is to keep your use of mongoose lightweight. Use schemas and queries but deeply tying your code to the remaining magical features is probably going to prove unwise in the long term.